# Ionic / Cordova won't deploy to Windows 10 phone

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-10-mobile

I have an existing Ionic app that I am trying to test on my Windows 10 mobile phone, but i cannot get Ionic (or Cordova) to deploy to the phone. I have added the Windows platform using `ionic platform add windows` and then tried to deploy using `ionic run windows --device -- --phone --archs="x86"` but that results in:

```
Deploying app package...
Unexpected error from installation:
Error: Not implemented
You may have previously installed the app with an earlier version of cordova-windows.
Ensure the app is uninstalled from the phone and then try to run again.
ERROR: Error: Not implemented
```

If i do `ionic run windows --list` to get a list of detected devices i get this:

```
Available windows devices:
0. Device (device)
Available windows virtual devices:
No devices found matching the specified criteria.
```

If I try to deploy directly to `0. Device (device)` then the app launches on my desktop computer.

Windows itself can "see" my Windows 10 phone and i can browse the contents of it in Windows Explorer.

I have also enabled Developer Mode on the phone so it will load apps from anywhere and I have purchased a Windows Developer License to see if that would help, but it didn't.

Finally, I tried installing the app using the Device Portal feature, but when I try to install it, I get this error:

```
Failure reason: Failed to start deployment. Failure text: No signature was present in the subject.
 (0x800b0100)
```

Has anyone else been able to deploy an Ionic / Cordova app to a Windows 10 device? If so, how did you set it up?

Comment: If you do a file new Windows 10 project can you deploy that to the phone?

Comment: I have just tried a new blank project through VS2015 and this worked. It deployed to the phone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
By default the cordova build command produces two packages: Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. To upgrade Windows package to version 10 the following configuration setting must be added to configuration file (config.xml).

`<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />`

This resolved the issue.

Comment: Got this error when building `2): error : "10.0.10240.0" is not a supported value for TargetPlatformMinVersion. Please change it on the Project Property page. [F:\Development\ionic2\Trackours\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]`

Answer (score -2):

On the Start Menu in Windows type `services.msc` and start the `Windows Phone IP Over Usb` service.